# Using regular expression, is there any other way in Javascript to extract date from string having time zone

Tags: javascript, regex, string, datetime

I'm using regular expression to extract date and time information from a given string.

> `2006-08-15T00:00:00+05:30`

I'm new to regular expression and the way I'm doing it is as follows:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```

I know that there may be some better way to do this. So, please if anybody has any knowledge on this topic please share and explain.
P.S: I also want to extract the time zone information.

Comment: are you looking to use only regex to extract it?

Comment: You can use this in your javascript: var datePart = str.split("T");
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Date: "+
                      datePart[0]+" Time: "+datePart[1].split("+")[0];

Answer (score 3):

If you want a non-regex solution, you can use this :

```
> new Date(Date.parse("2005-07-08T11:22:33+0000"))
Fri Jul 08 2005 13:22:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)
> new Date(Date.parse("2005-07-08T11:22:33+0000")).toUTCString()
"Fri, 08 Jul 2005 11:22:33 GMT"
```

And to get the timezone, you can use the `getTimezoneOffset()` function

```
var my_date = new Date(Date.parse("2005-07-08T11:22:33+0000"));
var timezone_offset = my_date.getTimezoneOffset();
```

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example, if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600 will be returned. Daylight savings time prevents this value from being a constant even for a given locale

Comment: Is it necessary to call Date.parse? I think we can directly pass in the string as the agrument to the Date ctor. function.

Comment: You're right, you can directly pass the date as a string to the `date()` function

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do using split method .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "2006-08-15T00:00:00+05:30";
    var res = str.split("T");
   console.log("date:" +res[0]);
  console.log("time:" +res[1]);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used `Date()` function, Then you can create `Date Object` to get all data without `regular expression` that you want.

**Example**

```
var Obj   = new Date();
var month = Obj.getMonth();
var date  = Obj.getDate();
var year  = Obj.getFullYear();
var hour  = Obj.getUTCHours();
var minutes = Obj.getUTCMinutes();
```

Here is the all [Date Object Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string an then you get an array, with the information:

```
 date.split(/[-\+:T]/g);
 //  ["2006", "08", "15", "00", "00", "00", "05", "30"]
```

Also, you should check if the string contains a + or a - before using the timezone.